# Is there any way to make this postgres query faster?

Tags: django, postgresql, query-optimization

So I have this query;

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    api_points
WHERE
    cat_level_5 = ANY(ARRAY['7223b580c20758c7','3e23543ccb9a2ef4','bbaec92cedb8a3bc',...])
    AND
    NOT cat_level_5 = ANY(ARRAY['8ccb9d2231a318e4'])
```

And there are about 2~3 million of records about geospatial points. The categories are hierarchical, there are 5 columns named as `cat_level_1`, `cat_level_2`, `cat_level_3`, `cat_level_4` and `cat_level_5`.

This query, with many level 5 categories specified, takes about 1-2 minutes to complete. I switched from using `IN` operator to `=` with arrays.

I can change the category structure or category data type for faster indexing.

When I add an index with `btree(cat_level_1, cat_level_2, cat_level_3, cat_level_4, cat_level_5)` it doesn't make much of a difference by the way.

Here is the [result of EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)](https://pastebin.com/XVxADWTp)

**Edit**

I edited the SQL query to this and the result is [this](https://pastebin.com/hfsdbPGv).

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['7223b580c20758c7','3e23543ccb9a2ef4','bbaec92cedb8a3bc',...]) cat_level_5
    WHERE cat_level_5 NOT IN ( SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['8ccb9d2231a318e4']) )
) categories
JOIN api_point
USING (cat_level_5)
```

The table structure is defined by this django model;

```py
class Point(models.Model):
    poi_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    poi_name = models.TextField(default = "")
    poi_address = models.TextField(default = "")
    location = models.TextField(default = "")
    location_info = models.TextField(default = "")
    history = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today)
    city_code = models.IntegerField()
    town_code = models.IntegerField()
    quarter_code = models.IntegerField()
    icon_url = models.TextField()

    cat_level_1 = models.TextField()
    cat_level_1_name = models.TextField()
    cat_level_2 = models.TextField()
    cat_level_2_name = models.TextField()
    cat_level_3 = models.TextField()
    cat_level_3_name = models.TextField()
    cat_level_4 = models.TextField()
    cat_level_4_name = models.TextField()
    cat_level_5 = models.TextField()
    cat_level_5_name = models.TextField()

    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()

    point = PointField(default = Point(0.0, 0.0))

    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The SQL table structure as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.api_poi
(
    poi_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    poi_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    poi_address text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    location text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    location_info text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    history date NOT NULL,
    city_code integer NOT NULL,
    town_code integer NOT NULL,
    quarter_code integer NOT NULL,
    icon_url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    lat double precision NOT NULL,
    lon double precision NOT NULL,
    last_modified timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    point geometry(Point,4326) NOT NULL,
    cat_level_1 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_1_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_2 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_2_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_3 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_3_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_4 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_4_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_5 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cat_level_5_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT api_poi_pkey PRIMARY KEY (poi_id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.api_poi
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: category_idx

-- DROP INDEX public.category_idx;

CREATE INDEX category_idx
    ON public.api_poi USING btree
    (cat_level_1 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, cat_level_2 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, cat_level_3 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, cat_level_4 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, cat_level_5 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: point_namex

-- DROP INDEX public.point_namex;

CREATE INDEX point_idx
    ON public.api_poi USING brin
    (point)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output it is hard to give a founded answer. Have you looked into the `ltree` extension and its index support to model your hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry, I will add the output soon, I added ltree extension but I am not sure if it's gonna make any difference as; if I were to search with only level 5, is it hierarchic at that state?

Comment: Hello again, I added result of `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: What tool formats the explain analyze output in this way and removes the row estimates? Anyway, this query looks like it returns huge number of rows (1962475) and "number of rows removed by filter" hints that it selects 88% of the table.

Comment: That doesn't look like EXPLAIN ANALYZE, it doesn't show the time it took to execute this query. Besides other information that is also missing.

Comment: The JSON output isn't really intended to be read by humans. The output of `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` would be more helpful

Comment: I used pgadmin's explain & analyze to execute it, let me fetch it in other way

Comment: I added the [new pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/XVxADWTp)

Comment: Tell me if you need any other information, I am willing to share information so people can have better understanding about what's going on but I don't know much about postgres optimization so I don't know what information to provide.

Comment: Why do you have a postive list of cat_level_5 as well as a negative list?  The negative (NOT) list is irrelevant provided the values do not appear in the positive list.

Comment: Negative list is to exclude blacklisted categories for a specific user

Comment: The row estimates are pretty good, but if this query selects 1.9 million rows there's no way it's going to execute in 1 millisecond. That said, 160 seconds is pretty slow. And since this is EXPLAIN ANALYZE we can't blame data transfer to the client. According to the buffer count, it reads about 3GB of data, which is a lot, but if you have nvme SSDs that should not take long.

Comment: So, there is something missing here. What are the other columns in this table? Rows seem pretty big but not big enough to be TOAST'ed, but you should still check if TOAST generates random access in toast table.

Comment: What are the other columns? Also this query is returning gigabytes of data, so what are you doing with the data?

Comment: I added a bunch of other details to my post, my local database is on harddrive but we run that on ssds on production servers so there will be a boost, 3gb of data maybe because of `address` and `point` entries on the database, I also tried indexing with using only category level 5 but it doesn't make any difference, I use psycopg2 as interface between python and postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example table foo has a text column x which contains numbers.

```
explain analyze select * from foo where x =any('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}'::TEXT[]);

 Gather  (cost=1000.00..62144.07 rows=99 width=10) (actual time=0.682..364.252 rows=99 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..61134.17 rows=41 width=10) (actual time=237.705..358.203 rows=33 loops=3)
         Filter: (x = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}'::text[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 333300
 Planning Time: 0.219 ms
 Execution Time: 364.292 ms
```

Note =ANY operator uses linear search in the array, which is slow if the array is long.

```
explain analyze select * from (select * from unnest('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}'::TEXT[]) x 
where x not in ('7','8')) a join foo using (x);
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1002.45..12146.72 rows=97 width=36) (actual time=0.904..44.894 rows=97 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.45..11137.02 rows=40 width=36) (actual time=24.904..38.844 rows=32 loops=3)
         Hash Cond: (foo.x = x.x)
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..9571.67 rows=416667 width=10) (actual time=0.007..16.592 rows=333333 loops=3)
         ->  Hash  (cost=1.24..1.24 rows=97 width=32) (actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=97 loops=3)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB
               ->  Function Scan on unnest x  (cost=0.00..1.24 rows=97 width=32) (actual time=0.020..0.040 rows=97 loops=3)
                     Filter: (x <> ALL ('{7,8}'::text[]))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 2
```

Using unnest produces a much faster hash join that avoids the linear search through the array. Additionally, I've added a "NOT IN" clause with the "Negative list to exclude blacklisted categories for a specific user" inside the subquery that generates the list of values to get, so the blacklisted values are removed from the list once at the beginning.

So, it generates the list of values you want, removes the blacklisted ones, hashes it, and scans the table looking up each row's value for this column in the hash.

This should make the query a bit faster, but it won't solve the main problem which is that it is reading 3GB of data.

> When I add an index with btree(cat_level_1, cat_level_2, cat_level_3, cat_level_4, cat_level_5) it doesn't make much of a difference by the way.

This is normal, you're not using cat_levels_1 to 4 in the query, so it can't use cat_level_5 which is at the end of the index column list. Perhaps an index on cat_level_5 would help, but I doubt it as this query is selecting a large fraction of the table.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer, I added a bunch of other details and the result of query, adapting your solution, there is a boost but I guess we are stuck because of that 3GB data. I need all of it for further filtering and manipulating bunch of other details so we can't cut that.

Comment: It's gonna take a while to transfer all the data to python and eat a ton of RAM on that side too...

Comment: Sadly, yes... but it isn't much of a problem as I don't fetch the data directly into python objects, instead i process them in consecutive fetching contexts so it basically retrieves data one at a time and does a bunch of other stuff while retrieveing it, this query is the most time consuming operation right now.

Comment: Is it the maximum possible enhancement we can do to this query? Would `ltree` affect it any better? It would be really hard to implement it to data insert statements in django, but if it's worth, it could be. If there would be no more performance improvement, then I will be checking it as solved as it helped to improve the performance.

Comment: no, indexing would help if you were selecting a tiny proportion of the rows in the table, but that's not the case here.